# How to create a list of reasource in SimPy

Tags: simpy

I would like to create a list of resources in SimPy. I would like to have the ability to access a resource by its index and not by a unique name. Something like:

```
for i in range(4)
    res[i]=simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2)
```

at the end of the loop, I will 4 resources I can access using its index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read on Python [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
res = []
for i in range(4):
    res.append(simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2))
```